# Cordova: Error: The WIFI_SERVICE must be looked up on the Application context or memory will leak on devices < Android N

Tags: android, cordova, gradle

I'm getting the follwoing error when trying to build my app:

```
Error: The WIFI_SERVICE must be looked up on the Application context or memory will leak on devices < Android N. Try changing this.cordova.getActivity() to this.cordova.getActivity().getApplicationContext() [WifiManagerLeak]
    Intent settingsIntent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_WIFI_SETTINGS);
                 ^

Explanation for issues of type "WifiManagerLeak":
On versions prior to Android N (24), initializing the WifiManager via
Context#getSystemService can cause a memory leak if the context is not the
application context. Change context.getSystemService(...) to
context.getApplicationContext().getSystemService(...).

2 errors, 0 warnings
```

I'm using node v6.11.2, cordova 6.5.0 and cordova-android 6.4.0 and gradle 4.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained in the [Github issue](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-diagnostic-plugin/issues/253), using the deprecated `api-22` branch of the plugin will result in this error because it's no longer maintained. Switch to using releases from the master branch and it will build fine with `cordova-android@6.4.0` and Gradle 4.

Both the master branch of `cordova-diagnostic-plugin` and `cordova-android@6.4.0` are backwardly-compatible to API 16.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**: as said by @DaveAlden updating cordova-diagnostic-plugin to current version and cordova-android to 6.4.0 worked.

---

WORKAROUND (in case that you can't update plugins):
Same situation is happening to me. My workaround was downgrading to Android Cordova < 6.4:

`cordova platform rm android`

And then:

`cordova platform add android@6.3` (or 6.2, depending on your plugins)

I'm still getting what causes the problem, but that worked for me as solution.

My analysis:

- Cordova Android 6.4.0 uses inside the project Gradle 4.1 and it is used for Android Plugin for Gradle 3.3.0+
- Cordova Android <6.4 uses Gradle 2.14.1, and it is used for Android Plugin for Gradle 2.3.0+

(Source: https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin.html)

---

**Edit**: seems to be a legit posible memory leak in the source file, exposed by Gradle or Android Plugin for Gradle.
In my case, was due the plugin `cordova.plugins.diagnostic.api-22` when running the task `:lintVitalRelease`. I left an issue in the plugin [Github](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-diagnostic-plugin/issues/253).

Which file of yours is marked with error? Is that due a plugin?

Comment: As explained in the Github issue, this is because you are using a deprecated branch of the plugin which is no longer maintained. Switch to using releases from the master branch and it will build fine with `cordova-android@6.4.0` and Gradle 4.

Comment: In my case, I need compatibility with API 19, so need that branch/version

Comment: both the master branch of `cordova-diagnostic-plugin` and `cordova-android@6.4.0` are backwardly-compatible to API 16

Comment: Yep, it was the same problem to me too. @DaveAlden, can you answer the question so I can accept it. Thanks!